# Script to Deny backup for Database owners

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-administration

I am looking for a script to Restrict Database owner  to  take database backups in SQL server. 
Till now i was using Sp_msforeachdb to create role and adding DENY Full and LOG backups to it.

Comment: And the problem with that approach is...?

Comment: if your need is to deny this operation on all databases then using sp_msforeachdb is not a bad idea :)

Comment: You might take a peek at this though before you continue using sp_msforeachdb. It will sometimes skip databases. https://sqlblog.org/2018/10/22/sp-ineachdb-2

Comment: One remark: denying permission to backup for people who are in the `db_owner` role only prevents accidents. It will not prevent someone in that role from simply resetting permissions to allow it anyway. If someone should definitely not be able to make a backup as a security demand, they shouldn't be an owner.